# Panel does not appear

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a panel with a really simple config:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.PanelPersonalData', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.panelpersonaldata',

requires: [
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.XTemplate'
],

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    tpl: [
                        'Data:',
                        '{salutation} {firstname} {lastname}<br />',
                        'Birthday: {birthday}<br />',
                        '{street} {number}<br />',
                        '{zip} {city}<br />',
                        'E-Mail: {email}',
                        '<p>Insurance: {priorInsurance}</p>',
                        '<p>',
                        'IBAN: {iban}<br />',
                        'BIC: {bic}',
                        '</p>',
                        '<p>Job: {occupationGroup}</p>'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The data for the placeholders is set correctly (I made a console log of it). But the pannel won't appear on the screen. If I remove the tpl config and add `html: 'TEST'` instead, I can see the correct output of TEST. What am I doing wrong here with the tpl config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I called `setData()` for the wrong panel. Instead of setting it to the panel with the placeholders, I used the parent panel. After changing this, everything works fine now.